# Galaxy Note 1 not listed under adb devices

Tags: android, adb, detect, data-recovery

I just installed android sdk. And trying to follow [these steps](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/02/12/guide-how-to-use-adb-sideload-to-update-a-nexus-without-root-or-custom-recovery/) to detect my device. Because my phone was disconnected & dead during an unfortunate/accidental/unwelcome software upgrade.

It's frozen on Samsung start up screen. I was able to use volume + power + home buttons to get into another black screen with `now send the package you want to apply to the device with adb sideload <file name>`. But not sure how to `sideload from adb` when I can't even detect my device. All I want is to retrieve my data & start up my device as normal.

Within the Command Prompt under platform tools, I typed `adb devices`. But no device listed. I am currently installing the Samsung Galaxy Note MTB device driver.

Can someone please guide me to the correct steps? There has to be a way to retrieve the data from the internal memory right?

Edit 1:

According to [this article, I am not sure if my phone is bricked or trap in a bootloop...First of all, lets get something straight. Most people use the term "bricked" improperly. A bricked phone means one thing: your phone won't turn on in any way, shape or form, and there's nothing you can do to fix it. It is, for all intents and purposes, as useful as a brick. A phone stuck in a boot loop is not bricked, nor is a phone that boots straight into recovery mode. These are things you can usually fix, and they're a lot more common than a truly bricked phone. If your phone is actually bricked, you won't be able to fix it yourself (but there are things you can do—see the end of this article)](http://lifehacker.com/5853519/how-do-i-fix-my-bricked-android-phone)

Edit 2:

**PC specs : Win Vista, 32-bit**

After installing MTP drivers I am at this point. However within `adb devices` command I only see `<aserial number> recovery`. It doesn't say `<serial number> device`

Do I still have a hope to get to my data?

[image]

Comment: I think you have bricked your phone. This happens when there is any problem that occur while phone is upgrading. If this is indeed your problem then this forum is not for you. Try searching http://forum.xda-developers.com/ for an unbrick tutorial.

Comment: @Rohan [Here's what really happened](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57588/galaxy-note-1-hangs-on-start-up-screen). I will search on "unbrick" jargon. I am just a C#, SQL programmer. I have no idea on mobile and this is my first exercise on an unexpected journey to rescue my data...

Comment: If your phone was indeed unplugged during and update then there are very little chances that your data will be recovered (contacts, messages and application data). I can help you in understanding the terms like ODIN and Downloading Mode etc. but there are very less chance of the data mentioned above

Comment: see this link it consist of a easy guide to unbrick N7000 http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1656635

Comment: You see phone was never meant to be upgraded in anyway. She just didn't know what she was doing. Simply connected my phone into a laptop which automatically upgrades any device connects to it. IN the first place, my phone was entirely drained. So why in the world did she even connect it to an upgrading system.. Well all these questions are out of the league now. All I want is to retrieve my contact list at minimum. I also see online there are softwares to [recover lost data during factory reset or `flashing`.](http://www.recovery-android.com/recover-data-from-android.html) Will those work?

Comment: I don't think that particular app will work since it requires a working phone `Step 3`. if you have CWM installed on your phone then maybe you can capture an image of your current ROM but other than that i don't think there is much.

Comment: @RohanKandwal my phone is detected in recovery mode in adb. Does it mean it's rooted? Because I want to retrieve the contacts data via adb pull. It says remote object does not exist.

Comment: no that doesn't mean that your phone is rooted but since your phone is being detected in recovery mode you can install a custom or stock rom on your device. Just initially don't try to clean/wipe your partitions.

Comment: Can I pull data without installing a custom rom? If I must, then what custom rom should I install? How should I install it? What commands? Can you help me out there?

Comment: why don't you post a question on xda? you will get professional help there with all the experts. Although I am not expert but I don't think that there is a way to get the data without any working on it. May be i am wrong, ask on xda they will tell you for sure. As far as Rom's are concerned. As i told you earlier just search for your phone on xda and you will find many Rom's available there. Each Rom will give you installation steps and if you still have a confusion you can watch a youtube video on "how to". Do what I told you and if still you have no clue then just post a comment here.

Comment: @RohanKandwal [I did(http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2543298). Now I am in [this stage.](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57656/adb-for-bootloop) Can you help me to access the data from sdcard function?

Comment: The fact that the Galaxy Note 1 publishes multiple USB interfaces may be a problem depending on host OS - for example, that CDC interface would cause an OSX host to be unable to see it is as an ADB device, because the kernel CDC driver claims the entire device.  It's possible windows has a similar issue.  I suspect it may be fairly straightforward to get it to work under linux (or a linux VM).

Answer (score 0):

Your phone may be stuck in a `BootLoop` It wont get detected using `adb` try using `FastBoot` if not you should contact your samsung service center to reload software . Your data is lost in this case.

**UPDATE**

try downloading `sp flash tool` check your phone is detected if so you can have some hope in data recovery

Comment: Samsung data centre is who, killed my device in the first place. I too think it's stuck in a bootloop...after reading online. There has to be some way to get the data back. Don't you think so? I mean even broken laptop hard discs can be read and data can be retrieved. I just don't get why we can't connect to a mobile devices kernal to retrieve the data...

Comment: Actually i had this situation somtimes back tried lot of ways wasted time and atlast go to my service center and reloaded software, only difference is my phone was rooted and i bricked it

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with the jargon rooted. Let me read about it. This situation is like "crash coursing android, android adb". May be (if you are from India) you have people to help you. I am from Singapore and I think most people who work in our Service centres are just part timers who have zero interest in either job or customer's needs. Because, it's extreme common sense to ask what customer wants before connect the device into anything any how...

Comment: try http://imadn2008.blogspot.in/2013/01/fix-boot-loop-for-samsung-galaxy-note.html

Comment: Will the above article delete all my data? Because I read, Flash & Custom ROM can delete all the data...Also which category should I use, one or two?

Comment: @aspiring I haven't used a galaxy note before so i don't know what android version it run on but you can try to install a custom rom of same version just don't format/clean any partition as you might have seen in the installation tutorials. Sometimes you may have be able to boot successfully then you can move your data and re-install the Rom after formating/cleaning the partitions.

Comment: 90% chance is that you will loose data, Note: dont keep data in internal sd card if its important , i learnt it through my mistakes, dont flash custom roms unless you are confident and have good knowledge , since you dont have any CWM dont try it , it will mess up again

Comment: @RohanKandwal can you please give me the steps to install custom rom of same version of galaxy note gt n7000? all I need to boot successfully. I believe after much research that my phone might have been disconnected and died during odin mode of software upgrades.

Comment: @Arju I am unable to get a good version of SP flash tool. Since there's still 10% of a chance that I have and could recover my data, could you please guide me through?

Comment: Im not a master of this title, any way i have a version of sp flash tool but i can post it for you at late evening, follow xda developers post there may be something useful for you

Comment: Currently what I want to know if it's possible to install an Android Custom Recovery? As it's meant for phones detectable or rooted properly. I am going to trying out the link you provided, to do so I need to install ODIN and custom recovery. When my device can't even be detected by my pc, `1`.can I still proceed to install a custom recovery? `2.` will [this be helpful to me](http://imadn2008.blogspot.in/2013/01/fix-boot-loop-for-samsung-galaxy-note.html)?

Comment: No you cant do that without device detection

Comment: @arju please take a [look at this and recommend where to proceed](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57656/adb-for-bootloop)

Comment: did your device listed in recovery mode in adb